# Activity title with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

Have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabGravity="fill" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

When toolbar collapsed I have a problem: Activity title overlaps with tab title.

[image]

What could be a problem?

Comment: What behaviour do you want, do you want the tabs to disappear or do you want the title to disappear?

Comment: @JoshLaird I want the title to disappear

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: Tabs disappear, but title not

Comment: put tabs out of collapsing toolbar and toolbar inside it. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186639/collapsingtoolbarlayout-and-hide-toolbar-while-scrolling) might help